# What protocol needs to be extended to allow the === operator for a generic type? (error: Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands)

Tags: swift, generics

I am getting the compiler error:

> Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands

where T is a generic type and I am just comparing two items of type T.

So I presume I need to tell it that the `===` operator can be used on T by making T extend a protocol. If it was `==` I would use `Equatable`, but I can't see what I am supposed to use for the identity comparison.

Or is there a work-around?

EDIT:

Here is a sample bit of code illustrating the problem. I have added here 'AnyObject' which causes a compilation error when the class is instantiated. If the 'AnyObject' is removed, it causes an error on the '==='.

```
import Foundation

protocol Messenger : AnyObject {
    func notify();
}

class PostOffice<T : AnyObject> {
    var messengers : [T] = []

    func addMessenger(messenger : T) {
        messengers.append(messenger)
    }

    func deleteMessenger(messenger : T) {
        for i in 0 ..< messengers.count {
            if messengers[i] === messenger {    // error if AnyObject not used
                messengers.removeAtIndex(i)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    func handleDelivery(messenger : T) {} // to be overridden

    func deliver() {
        for messenger in messengers {
            handleDelivery(messenger)
        }
    }
}

let p : PostOffice<Messenger> = PostOffice<Messenger>()  // error if AnyObject used
```

The error in this case is:

> Using 'Messenger' as a concrete type conforming to 'AnyObject' is not support.

Comment: What's the compilation error when using `<T: AnyObject>`?

Comment: And oh by the way, your `deleteMessenger` has either a crash or bug in it if the same object is in there multiple times. You need to work back to front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the ways `===` is defined:

```
public func ===(lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

and

```
public func ===<L : AnyCollectionType, R : AnyCollectionType>(lhs: L, rhs: R) -> Bool
```

You can see you need ensure `T` conforms to either `AnyObject` or `AnyCollectionType`. For example:

```
func f<T : AnyObject>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a === b
}
```

or

```
func f<T : AnyCollectionType>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a === b
}
```

Comment: I am mobile now, so I can't check, but conceivably, we could make a protocol that has the `===` function (like `Equatable`) then extend `AnyObject` and `AnyCollectionType` to conform to the protocol, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error `Using 'ProtocolB' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported` when I try to use this elsewhere. But that might be a different issue.

Comment: I think the only solution is to use AnyObject directly in PostOffice (no generic type) and cast it when it comes out.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing generics and protocols in a way that doesn't make sense.

```
class PostOffice<T : AnyObject> {
```

This means that you want PostOffices to be wrappers around some *specific* type. Not "any type that conforms to such and such protocol," but one, and exactly one, type. OK, that's fine.

```
let p : PostOffice<Messenger> = PostOffice<Messenger>()  // error if AnyObject used
```

This says you want `p` to be a `PostOffice` that wraps any type that happens to conform to `Messenger`. Well, that's not what you said you wanted `PostOffice` to be. You said you wanted it to be type-specialized. So which is it?

Based on your naming, I'm assuming you *really* want `PostOffice` to accept any `Messenger`. That's fine, but then it shouldn't be generic:

```
class PostOffice {
    var messengers : [Messenger] = []

    func addMessenger(messenger : Messenger) {
        messengers.append(messenger)
    }

    func deleteMessenger(messenger : Messenger) {
        for i in 0 ..< messengers.count {
            if messengers[i] === messenger {    // error if AnyObject not used
                messengers.removeAtIndex(i)
                return
            }
        }
    }
    func handleDelivery(messenger : Messenger) {} // to be overridden

    func deliver() {
        for messenger in messengers {
            handleDelivery(messenger)
        }
    }
}
```

That said, you're not using `notify()` anywhere, which sounds like you actually want `PostOffice` to work on non-Messengers. (Not sure how that's useful, but it seems to be what you wrote). That's fine, too, but then you need to some actual type (not a protocol) that you specialize `PostOffice` with:

```
class SomeMessenger: Messenger {
    func notify() {}
}

let p = PostOffice<SomeMessenger>()
```

If you really mean that `PostOffice` should be specialized, but you want in this case to accept any kind of `Messenger`, then you need [type-erasure](http://robnapier.net/erasure) so that you can create a concrete type that wraps `Messenger`:

```
final class AnyMessager: Messenger {
    let _notify: () -> Void
    init(messenger: Messenger) {
        _notify = messenger.notify
    }
    func notify() { _notify() }
}

let p = PostOffice<AnyMessager>()
```

(This is the solution to many Swift protocol issues, but it doesn't feel right in this case. I suspect you really wanted `PostOffice` to require a `Messenger`. But I don't really understand your `PostOffice` type. It mixes generics with abstract classes, which doesn't really feel very Swifty. I suspect you really want to redesign these types.)

You may be interested in [this implementation of an Observable](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/58e00f3c3260950be0dc). It shows a different way to register and remove listeners without requiring `===` or a `notify` method.

Comment: I didn't dump all code. In reality, `PostOffice` is not instantiated, but is used as an abstract class. It manages the listeners added to it and provides some other logic (not shown). So `deliver` does other stuff, but the stuff specific to each type T is handled in the derived classes. `Messenger` is badly named, but is a particular instance of a protocol for something receiving the deliveries. There are others. The only thing they have in common is that I need to do the identity comparison, which is why I need the '===' check. I will read your suggestions and see if I can refactor. Thanks!